# MySQL two-column unique key

Tags: mysql, database, key, unique-key

I know that i can make two columns unique keys, but that's not exactly what i want.

I want that for example if `col1='1', col2='2'` then there can't be another row with `col1='1', col2='2'`, but totally possible to do the following:

```
+--------+--------+
|  col1  |  col2  |
+--------+--------+
|    1   |    1   |
|    1   |    2   |
|    2   |    1   |
|    2   |    2   |
+--------+--------+
```

while this is impossible:

```
+--------+--------+
|  col1  |  col2  |
+--------+--------+
|    1   |    1   |
|    1   |    1   |
+--------+--------+
```

Making both unique keys is not an option as in `col1='1', col2='1'` and `col1='1', col2='2'` `col1` is the same and that's not allowed if both are unique keys.

Comment: what about concatenating the two columns to a third column and make that the unique key?

Comment: You can place a unique constraint on multiple keys, e.g. `ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`col1`, `col2`);`

Comment: You want a two field unique key as  @GiorgosBetsos says

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need `composite unique index`.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE KEY `uidx` (`col1`, `col2`);
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need to declare a unique index between the two columns `col1`, and `col2`:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
  `col1` int, 
  `col2` int,
   UNIQUE `unique_index`(`col1`, `col2`)
);
```

If you try to insert `1, 1`, into col1 and col2, you will get the following error:

```
Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'unique_index'
```

You can try it yourself [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34c641).